# Swift3/Alamofire4 migration, having to make all elements 'as AnyObject' for [String: AnyObject]

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I have old code from the previous Swift/Alamofire version that worked fine before

```
parameters = ["name":name, "description":description, "location":location, "start_time":start_time , "end_time":end_time/* ..etc */] as [String: AnyObject]

Alamofire.request(.PUT, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .json, headers: ["Authorization": auth_token, AppVersionKey: AppVersionValue]).validate().responseJSON() { response in

    print("Status code of default pic call: \(response.response?.statusCode)")
            }
```

I know I now have to switch it to

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, ... , encoding: JSONEncoding.default ...)
```

But I'm getting Xcode errors for `parameters` and the fix-it is just adding `as AnyObject` to each value in the k,v pairs which then results in an "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time ..." error. How am I supposed to do this with the new Swift3 and Alamofire4? Not even sure if this is a Swift error or Alamofire migration issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire parameter only accepts \[String : Anyobject\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733630/alamofire-parameter-only-accepts-string-anyobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to `parameters` with a literal of type `[String: Any]` cast to a `[String: AnyObject]` which is why the compiler is complaining.

If you remove the cast at the end of the assignment and update the type of `parameters` to `[String: Any]` it should work.

This is due to a Swift 3 change which basically replaced many former uses of `AnyObject` with `Any` so that structs and enums would also be accepted.